# ODI Declare variable

Tags: sql, oracle, variables, parameter-passing, etl

I have ODI ( Oracle Data Integrator)scenario in which I need to give some input parameters when the ODI scenario is executed. For this I have created the declared variable and used the same in one of the interface but  when I ran the scenario input parameters are prompted as desired given  the necessary value, the scenario is successful but I see no value under variable and interface loaded with zero records. Please share your thoughts.

Declared variable text data type as I am passing string value.

Comment: Hi. Can you post some images with what you described:map - where you used the variable, scenario-when you launched it?